# Notification of stationary Sidekiq or Resque queues

Tags: resque, sidekiq

Is there an easy way to receive notifications when a Sidekiq or Resque queue is not moving?

We're having issues where our workers randomly die and the queue ends up stationary. While we work on solving the dying worker issues we want to preempt support calls for stalled jobs.

Comment: Trying to understand worker over here means job processing worker or resque worker

Comment: either. The point is that whatever processes the queue fails to operate and we want to know when the queue is not moving

Comment: You can monitor the queue length and see if getting decreasing our the time

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a module that checks the workers periodically to see when they were last ran.

I created a Cron Job that calls killStaleWorkers(). It basically checks the redis queue to see what time the current workers started running. In my case, if jobs ran more than 2 minutes ago, it meant it was stale, and probably froze. When that happens, you can do several things, such as restarting sidekiq (which I did). You can pass in any amount of time you want, depending on how long jobs normally take.

Here's my code.

```
class SidekiqDoctor
    def percentageStale(workers, staleTime, redis)
        stale = 0

        workers.each do |worker|
            key = "worker:" + worker + ":started"
            timeStarted = Time.parse(redis.get(key))

            if(timeStarted == nil)
                timeStarted = Time.now
            end

            puts "Key: " + key + ", Time started: " + timeStarted.to_f.to_s + ", Stale Time: " + staleTime.to_f.to_s

            if(timeStarted.to_f <= staleTime.to_f)
                stale = stale + 1
            end
        end

        percentage = (stale.to_f / workers.size.to_f) * 100

        return percentage
    end

    def killStaleWorkers(staleTimeAgo = 2.minutes, redis = Sidekiq.redis { |x| x })
        workers = redis.smembers("workers")
        currentMachine = Socket.gethostname
        existingWorkers = {} #key is PID, value is array of workers

        workers.each do |worker|
            tokens = worker.split(":")
            machine = tokens[0]
            pid = tokens[1].split("-")[0]

            puts "Machine: " + machine + ", PID: " + pid
            if(machine == currentMachine)
                begin
                    Process.getpgid( pid .to_i)
                    if(existingWorkers[pid] == nil)
                        existingWorkers[pid] = []
                    end

                      existingWorkers[pid] << worker

                rescue Errno::ESRCH
                    #pid doesn't exist
                    redis.srem("workers", worker)
                    puts "PID doesn't exist: " + pid
                end
            end  
        end

        pids = existingWorkers.keys
        staleTime = Time.now - staleTimeAgo

        puts "Stale time: " + staleTime.to_s
        restarted = false
        percentStale = 0

        for pid in pids
            puts "Testing PID: " + pid.to_s
            percentStale = percentageStale(existingWorkers[pid], staleTime, redis)

            puts "Stale Time %: " + percentStale.to_s
            #restart Sidekiq by touching restart.txt, which forces God to restart it
            if(percentStale >= 25)
                restartGod
                restarted = true
            end
        end

        return [restarted, percentStale]
    end



end
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Henley, I ended up implementing a lil code too :)

Answer (score 0):

There wasn't any existing tool out there for keeping an eye on slow moving/stationary queues. So I've written a tiny gem that adds some Sidekiq middleware and provides a task that will send messages to Campfire when queues start to turn stale.

https://github.com/mpowered/sidekiq-nag